# Tiffen telephoto converter 1.5x37mm

Tags: lens, lens-adapter

I have a Tiffen telephoto converter 1.5x37mm is it any good and what is it used for?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It adds some "zoom" to a lens/camera by being attached in front of it using the filter thread.

37mm is quite small so this is likely for a compact camera or an action camera (but high zooms are rarely used on the latter).

These things have dubious value. The optical quality is rarely good and they "eat light" while being used on cameras with sensitivity-challenged sensors, so they can be used only in very good lighting conditions.

Tiffen ones aren't the worst but they aren't worth much (you find them for 10-15 dollarss on eBay).